# Way to reload XSLT without building a project again in Netbeans

Tags: netbeans

When im working  with Netbeans is there a way i can see my changed XSLT in the browser without building again my project? I have to change my XSLT very often to see the results and If i build my projects too many times the system hangs. Im working with ubuntu 10.04.

Comment: you may want to describe your situation a bit more completely.  Are you using an Ant based web app project? Which server are you deploying your app onto? Which version of NB are you using? etc.

Answer (score 0):

You will need to read the XSLT from a file, instead of getting the XSLT data using the getResourceAsStream(String) methods on Class and ClassLoader. This because once the data has been found by the classloader, the data is not reread... even if it changes on disk.

That isn't a good long term architecture, though.

You should file a bug in the NetBeans issue tracker so the IDE/server combo stops having the problem...

> and If i build my projects too many
>   times the system hangs